# Storing The Sliced Character from .slice Method

Tags: javascript, string, slice

When I utilise the slice method like so:

```
"Hello".slice(0,-1);
```

The result I get will be "Hell". Then if I run through that again using the same code, I will get "Hel".

Is there a way that I can extract and store into a variable the actual character that was sliced off, in this case "H" or on the second run "e", and not just the remainder of the string?

Comment: how about `slice(0,1)` ?

Comment: *"The result I get will be "ello""* - No it won't, it will be `"Hell"`.

Comment: Oops, thanks for the check @nnnnnn.

Comment: Thanks @abhishekkannojia but if I try to do it more than once it will keep returning "H" and not progress through the string and keep storing the next character is slices off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use a second `.slice()` on the original string.

For example, where `"Hello".slice(0,-1);` returns all but the last character, `"Hello".slice(-1)` returns only the last character.

```
var input = "Hello";
var removed = input.slice(-1);       // "o"
var remaining = input.slice(0, -1);  // "Hell"
```

I don't think there's a more generic solution than that, because `.slice()` also lets you extract the *middle* of a string, in which case you'd need *two* extra calls to get the two parts being removed.

Demo:

```js
var input = "Hello";
var allRemoved = [];
var removed;
while (input != "") {
  allRemoved.push(removed = input.slice(-1));
  input = input.slice(0, -1);
  console.log("'" + removed + "' removed, leaving '" + input + "'");
}
console.log("Removed: " + allRemoved.join(", "));
```

Alternatively, if you only care about removing characters one at a time, you could forget about `.slice()` and instead convert the string to an array and use [`.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) or [`.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) to remove the character at the beginning or end respectively:

```js
var input = "Hello";
var inArr = input.split("");
while (inArr.length > 0) {
  console.log(inArr.pop());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I think that's the same methodology behind what @abhishekkannojia was suggesting. But it stops there. I can't progress through my string and extract and then store each following character that I slice off the string?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but I've added a demo that lops off the characters one at a time and puts them in an array. I'm sure you can adapt from there...

Comment: You're welcome. I just updated to show an alternative way to take the string one character at a time.

Comment: Thanks again, @nnnnnn! I don't understand why my question keeps getting down voted though :(

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most efficient way to do this but you can turn yout string as an array with .split, then use .splice to remove certain elements ( letters ) and store them as a variable. Finally you turn your variable of removed letters back to a string using .join

```js
let name = 'David'
let arrayname = name.split('')
let chosenLetters = arrayname.splice(0,2)
let finalLetters = chosenLetters.join('')
console.log(finalLetters) //should output Da
```

For split and join I recommend you leave the argument as (''). For .splice you can find in the docs for js how to select specific letters. In my example I am saying "Start at index 0 and cut the first 2 elements". Splice has many other ways to select an index so I recommend you read the docs.

In one line of code it can be generalized to :

```js
  let name = 'David'
  let finalLetters = name.split('').splice(0,2).join('')
  console.log(finalLetters) //should output Da
```